# jquery on click not retaining value?

Tags: jquery, click, live, attr

i have this situation:

```
$id = 123456;

<a href="<?=$id?>" id="id"></a>
<a href="100" id="count">100</a>

$('#count').live("click", function() {
    var votes = $("#count").attr("href");
    var id= $("#id").attr("href");
    var dataStrings = 'id=' + id+ '&votes=' + votes;
});
```

if i do a alert or console log i get only the count value: `id=undefined&votes=100`

any ideas on what the problem might be?

thanks

edit:

the $id var is a php one. and if i view source i see the number being echoed there:

```
<a href="123456" id="id"></a>
<a href="100" id="count">100</a>
```

Comment: Are you sure your server supports the short tag <?= ?>. Maybe try changing this to long tags <?php echo ?>. That is of course you are using this in context of PHP.

Comment: $id = 123456; -> is that server side? when you view source, what do you get? Do you see the the the id get bound?

Comment: 2 cents: I believe it's a best practice to reserve the dollar sign with variable names ($VariableName) for jQuery objects.

Comment: based on chunk of code you provided, it should work, unless you have duplicate element with id "id" somewhere else..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that you have another element in your html with a duplicate id="id" but without "href" attribute before the code you posted here.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but I'd say part of the problem could be your odd use of numeric values for hrefs.  I'd make those values some other attribute.

Comment: dont think thats the problem though. should be able to get numeric value